# Android resume from one fragment activity to another and vice versa

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I want to create Android app where there are 3 main **FragmentActivities**, A (main), B, and C, also there are other sub activities. this app can go from activity A to activity B or activity C freely, and vice versa without starting new activity unless it is not started or finished. so how i can achieve this?

----- Edited -----

Comment: Better to use fragments instead Activity.

Comment: so you mean to warp A,B,C as fragment of a fragmentActivity, but the activities itself is a fragments activity, is it save to create fragments in fragment?

Comment: Check this link [NestedFragments](http://xperiment-andro.blogspot.nl/2013/02/nested-fragments.html)

Comment: @SilentKiller [NestedFragments](http://xperiment-andro.blogspot.nl/2013/02/nested-fragments.html) seems what i looking for, thanks, ill check it out, and as usual if it work, please move your comment as answer.

Comment: so in the end i use this method, one FragmentActivity multiple dataset for page adapter, so when user switch view, the tabhost will removed and readded, and the viewpager adapter will be re-set.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At any point in time there is only one Activity that is active. They will be finished and they will be garbage collected.

What you can do is set your launch mode to single task and see if it helps in your situation.

Comment: They will be paused and then stopped after some time. You cannot control it. You can still implement state saving but fragmens are better for this.

Comment: it depends on device memory.

Comment: Which you cannot control either. You will also find users that have a top notch smartphone and set "don't keep activities" to true in the dev settings.

Comment: ya agreed with that. but my activity remain in memory for up to some times. it won't destroy.

Comment: one solution may be to warp A,B,C as a fragment of a fragmentActivity, but the activities itself is a fragments activity, is it save to create fragments in fragment?

Comment: You cannot know. What if the user turns off the screen or starts a 3d game while using your app. Creating your app like that is a waste of time as it will be low quality and lose state.

Comment: @DeckyFx Yea I would do that. You can swap the fragments in the main activity, this will also create faster screen transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Use Navigation-Drawer or Swipe View..fragments are your solution. So you'll have FragmentActivity and 3 fragment A B C to replace

Comment: @DeckyFx Activity or FragmentActivity are the same. You cannot use more than 1 activity and the other will be to pause or destroy. Also fragments keep the same work of activity, you only call the context or Activity from fragment. You can add beautiful transation and keep ram memory clean

Comment: i just mean, the activity itself is fragment activity, so if i wrap them as fragment activity, then it is fragment in fragment...... forget it, @SilentKiller give some link about this. Anyway, thanks ^_^

Answer (score -1):

I will move activities layout to views, and write within one Activity, use hide/show to change to A, B, C.

Comment: That's gonna cause a serious layout mess and you will have a lot of resources in RAM